# possible number of rectangle in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I am going through a algorithm of calculating the sum of a region of matrix. And I read a solution  to pre-compute the sum to get better result.I want to calculate the possible number of rectangle(sub Maxtix) in a 2d-matrix of size mXn.

Can anybody explain solution using permutation and combination.

Comment: You're not clear. Express yourself clearly or your question will surely be closed.

Comment: To precompute the sum you need to express it with a reccurence relation.

Answer (score 2):

Start form the simplest case first:

```
Start with m x n, thats 1 rectangle.
Reduce n by 1, that gives another 2.
Reduce n by 1, that gives another 3.
Reduce n by 1, that gives another 4.
```

Do you see the pattern?

When n gets down to 1, subtract 1 from m, and start over:

```
Start with m-1 x n, thats 2 rectangles.
Reduce n by 1, that gives another 4.
Reduce n by 1, that gives another 6.
Reduce n by 1, that gives another 8.
```

Are you seeing the pattern yet..?

Now you extrapolate to m-2, m-3, m-4, ..., 1.

Now start form the beginning reducing n first, then n (or simply double all results, except mxn).

And the sum of all those results is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an algorithm it is a counting problem. 
try to count the amount of rectangulars in a 1X1 matrix and 1X2 2X1 3X2 etc. and then you will see

```
num_of_rect(mXn) = sum(i*j) for 0<i<m+1; 0<j<n+1
```

---

in python:

```py
def countRect(n,m):
    return sum([i*j for i in xrange(n+1) for j in xrange(m+1)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print countRect(2,3)
```

gives `18`

Comment: Number of rectangles in a matrix of 2x3 is 18.
Your algorithm is simply returning the value of m*n

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rectangle_counts]

You can count all rectangles a*b with a,b>=2 by simply choosing which rows and which columns to include (see picture):

```
C(m,2)*C(n,2)
```

You can count a*1 rectangles with a>=2 via

```
C(m,2)*n
```

and 1*b rectangles with b>=2 via

```
m*C(n,2)
```

and 1*1 matrices via:

```
m*n
```

so add these for the final answer:

```
C(m,2)*C(n,2) + C(m,2)*n + m*C(n,2) + m*n
```

Comment: This is also equal to C(m+1,2)*C(n+1,2)

Answer (score 1):

Number of possible Rectangles of any size in an m x n matrix

mn + (m-1)(n-1) + (m-2)(n-1) + .. + (m-m+1)(n-1) + (m-1)(m-2) + .. + (m-m)(n-n)

Sum { i * j } for i in [0,m]; j in [0,n]

Comment: what is SO algorithm ? and what is jslatex ? and how are they related to this post ??

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't directly relevant to your answer: SO is this website, and jslatex is a javascript library to transform latex mathematical notations into images. Have a look on cs.stackexchange.com for an idea of what I'm talking about.